# Selenium screen shot generation using Python script for the remote web page - getting error as about:neterror

Tags: python, selenium

Tools used : 
Geckodriver : 0.11.1
Mozilla Firefox : 52.8.0
Xvfb, python 2.7.5

Error Msg :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/app/wordpress/take-screenshot-2.py", line 37, in <module>
    browser.get(feed_item_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 326, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=inadequateSecurityError&u=https%3A//www.sysadmit.com/2018/06/veeam-backup-exclusiones-antivirus-Windows-Defender-PowerShell.html&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=The%20website%20tried%20to%20negotiate%20an%20inadequate%20level%20of%20security.
```

Comment: So you booting your OS and getting this error? Or you getting this on your android or iOS device? Care to explain what you did and when you get the error?

Comment: @Senthil `veeam-backup-exclusiones-antivirus-Windows-Defender-PowerShell.html` is causing the havoc

Comment: I m having a Python script which is generating thumbnail using selenium packages  for the given remote web site URL.

Comment: @DebanjanB : There is no proper solution yet. If so, please share it

Comment: @Senthil The error you are seeing `Reached error page: about:neterror?` is pretty generic and I have pointed you the exact discussion on Stackoverflow which contains all the links to the relevant github discussions. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question with all the relevant details along with code block, relevant HTML and error stack trace.

Comment: After using chrome browser and chrome driver this issue resolved. The issue is due to Firefox / Gecko driver